# Maven error: "Cannot resolve com.github.ConnorLinfoot:ActionBarAPI:1.5.4"

Tags: xml, maven, repository

I am creating a minecraft spigot plugin and I have to include an API from GitHub.

I used jitpack.io to get the code required to fetch the repository from GitHub and got an error: "Cannot resolve com.github.ConnorLinfoot:ActionBarAPI:1.5.4".

My pom.xml code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ecohub</groupId>
    <artifactId>DeathSwap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ConnorLinfoot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ActionBarAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the dependency ActionBarAPI has no release and have no version published on the public repository that you placed on your pom.xml.
While using [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/), in cases like this, you can place the commit version of the git project that you are looking for. In your case, checking the github page of [ActionBarAPI](https://github.com/ConnorLinfoot/ActionBarAPI/), the project has no releases yet. If you decide to use even without any public release, with jitpack, you can refer the last commit hash as the version of your dependency. In other words, this should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ConnorLinfoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>ActionBarAPI</artifactId>
    <version>5b2d642d3df240cfd2545effcdcacec38405f9cf</version><!-- Replace with the last commit hash that you are looking for -->
</dependency>
```